# Terraform variables

Tags: variables, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to define some variables for aws_key_path and name but I get an error when terraform init

```
# variables.tf

variable "aws_key_path" {
  aws_key_path = "Users/user/Documents/folder/filename.pem"
}
variable "aws_key_name" {
  aws_key_name = "filename"
}
```

```
# main.tf

module "us-west-1" {
  source       = "./some_sorce"
  aws_key_path = "${var.aws_key_path}"
  aws_key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
  aws_region   = "us-west-1"
  amis         = "${var.amis}"

  providers = {
    aws.source = "aws.us-west-1"
  }
}
```

get an error when init:

- variable[aws_key_path]: invalid key: aws_key_path

what is wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are not environment variables.

Terraform variables are defined as follows:

```
variable "aws_key_name" {
  default = "filename"
}
```